# How to send data from BroadcastReceiver to Fragment in android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, fragment, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make an chatting app.I have a `SlidingDrawer` Activity and it has many fragments and among which `ChatFragment` is one.Now when i am sending message to my friend , i have a `Chatting Window` and if any message comes from `GCM` service and i am in `ChatFragment` then this message will go to that Fragment and update the listview as i want to update the chatWindow when any message comes while chatting Now I tried to do like below.
**GcmIntentService :**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            // Since we're not using two way messaging, this is all we really to check for
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Logger.getLogger("GCM_RECEIVED").log(Level.INFO, extras.toString());

                showToast(extras.getString("message"));
                Intent sendData = new Intent("chatupdater");
                sendData.putExtra("msg", extras.getString("message"));
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sendData);
                Log.i("chat","i am in GCMIntentService");


            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Here i am starting a broadcastreceiver in onHandleIntent().

**ChatBroadCastReceiver:**

```
public class ChatBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("chat","I am in ChatBroadCastReceiver");
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        Log.i("chat",msg);



        //Intent data = new Intent("chatupdater");
        //Intent data = new Intent("chatupdater");
        //data.putExtra("key","data");
        //data.putInt("fragmentno",1); // Pass the unique id of fragment we talked abt earlier
        //context.sendBroadcast(intent);


    }
}
```

This is my `ChatBroadCastReceiver` class and if any message comes it successfully receives at the `onReceive()` method.Now i want to send this message to the Fragment.What i tried , i registered the Fragment with it and tried to get the same data at the `onReceive()` of `ChatFragment`.But it didn't call.I tried to see by logging.

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    //ChatBroadCastReceiver mReceiver;
    private EditText et_chat;
    Bundle mailData;
    String caller_mail;
    private ListView chatListview;
    private ChatWindowAdapter chatWindowAdapter;
    private List<ChatSession>PreviousChatSession;
    private List<ChatInfo> chatListItems;
    Button chat_send;
    public ChatFragment() {

    }

    public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("chat","I am in BroadCastReceiver");
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver();
        //getActivity().registerReceiver(new ChatBroadCastReceiver(),new IntentFilter("chatupdater"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(new ChatBroadCastReceiver(),new IntentFilter("chatupdater"));
        Log.i("chat", "I am in onCreate");

    }
```

**Now how can i get the message which i got in the Broadcastreceiver to the onReceive() of ChatFragment??**

Comment: What is a use of LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance()?

Comment: I got this quote from one answer." if your Broadcast Receiver is in a fragment, register it using LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(onNotice); and unregister it using LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(onNotice);".But I tried to do without LocalBroadCastManager but same result.

Comment: if u know any other way you can suggest me. @ Dhaval patel

Comment: Okay I did some research on LocalBroadcastManager and found [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) very helpfull. May Be Not Related to your question.

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater")); try this one.

Comment: I want you to comment mReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver(); line and try LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater"));

Comment: can u explain me why it worked this way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Register your Broadcast You are using:

```
mReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater"));
```

So you will Only receive Broadcast on `ChatBroadCastReceiver` class. Because mReceiver is a Instance of  `ChatBroadCastReceiver` class.

Now to Receive broadcast Message on anonymous class that you have created in your `ChatFragment` you need to register that like below code. Where mReceiver is a Instance of anonymous BroadcastReceiver class that you have implemented in your `ChatFragment` class.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater"))
```

To Receive Broadcast Message Both on ChatFragment and ChatBroadCastReceiver you need to register broadcast receiver twice.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater"))

ChatBroadCastReceiver mChatBroadCastReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mChatBroadCastReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater"))
```

Hope this answer will help you to understand your problem.

Comment: You mean to ChatBroadCastReceiver mChatBroadCastReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mChatBroadCastReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater")) to include in ChatBroadCastReceiverclass or in ChatFragment onCreate().

Comment: @setu basak yeh you are right. Register with mChatBroadCastReceiver if you want to receive broadcast in  ChatBroadCastReceiver class or Rigister with mReceiver if you want to receive broadcast in you ChatFragment class.

Comment: I am confused where you want to me to write these lines
ChatBroadCastReceiver mChatBroadCastReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mChatBroadCastReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater"))..You want to me to write in ChatBroadCaster class onCreate().

Comment: If you want to receive broadcast in your ChatFragment class just use ocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater")); You have already written a code for mReceiver. So no need to do anything else.

Comment: If you want to receive broadcast in ChatBroadCastReceiver class, Then only register like. ChatBroadCastReceiver mChatBroadCastReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mChatBroadCastReceiver ,new IntentFilter("chatupdater")).

Comment: mReceiver = new ChatBroadCastReceiver(); Doesn't have any meaning in your code. So remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

- Create an interface which will have a method like this.

  `public interface DemoListener {
      public void receiveMessage(String message);
  }`

Now implement this in your fragment and register the listener in `BroadcastReceiver`, now as soon as your broadcast receiver receives any message it will be available to your fragment via this Listener.
Hope this helps.

Comment: how you can register the listner in BroadcastReceiver