# Android:How to send data Activity to Fragment using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

Send data from `Activity` to `Fragment` in Android using `BroadcastReceiver`. I know there is varies way to communicate `Activity` to `Fragment`.

But i don't know how to send data and receive using `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver in order to pass data from another Activity to Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442782/broadcastreceiver-in-order-to-pass-data-from-another-activity-to-fragment)

Comment: Possibility of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442782/broadcastreceiver-in-order-to-pass-data-from-another-activity-to-fragment

Comment: If you want to use only broadcast reciever check the answer here which uses local broadcast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059380/how-to-send-data-from-broadcastreceiver-to-fragment-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent("KEY");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your fragment

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mNotificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUi();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mNotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter("KEY"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying sand string with   intent.putExtra("con_number", con_num); and receive in  onReceive method  if (action.equals("Continer_number")) {
                searchText = intent.getExtras().getString("con_number"); did not work

Comment: it should work, just check if you are sending and receiving in the right way in intent.